# how to verify if MTU 9000 configured properly on all component

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

we want to test the network on all Linux machines

after all machines and switches configured to MTU=9000

the reason for that is because inconsistent MTU configuration can cause huge problem

so in our hadoop cluster we have ~50 machines and also switches that configured also

what are the Linux CLI that can approve that all linux / switches configured with MTU=9000

as all know ifconfig -a , show the MTU value

but we want to test it on each machine that MTU is real working

Comment: related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451647/can-jumbo-frames-mtu-9000-be-set-on-vm-machines/451649#451649 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/426113/how-to-know-if-my-servers-should-use-jumbo-frames-mtu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ping across your infrastructure forcing a suitable packet size and setting the `DF` (Don't Fragment) bit.

Relevant ping flags are `-s` to set the packet size and `-Mdo` to set the `DF` bit.

For example on my system (normal 1500 MTU):

```
$> ping 10.10.10.1 -s 9000 -Mdo
PING 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1) 9000(9028) bytes of data.
ping: local error: Message too long, mtu=1500
```

it gives an error (because my PC is **not** configured with Jumbo frames).

Please keep in mind that if Layer2 MTU is 9000, the ping size should be 28 bytes less, so use 8972 as packet size:

```
ping A.DD.RE.SS -s 8972 -Mdo
```

Comment: first thank you so much your answer is very clear , so what we get for example from ping $IP -s 9000 -Mdo    ( consider that IP configured to MTU=9000 )

Comment: @yael simply ping will respond instead of returning an error, for example `ping 192.168.0.5` will respond `64 bytes from 192.168.0.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.180 ms`

Comment: so , if MTU=9000 was configured on all machines in the cluster , include the switches / router etc  ( as you know we have 50 machines ) then from each machine to every each machine we need to get  --> respond 64 bytes from 192.168.0.5: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.180 ms   , am I right ?

Comment: @yael Sure, please keep in mind that with an MTU of 9000 (layer2), the packet size for ping should be <=8972, so use `ping -s 8972`, you should get a response like `8972 bytes from ...`.

Comment: so lets summary , in order to  complete verification of MTU=9000 we need to do ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -s 8972 -Mdo , from each machine to all other machine in the cluster , so this will covered all test , am I right  ?

Comment: @yael yes, that's correct. Well, maybe you won't need to do the test on **all** the machines, but we don't know your network topology so it's up to you to do all the tests you deem necessary.

Comment: just note , we have all machines IP's but not the switches IP's , is it important to do also to the switches ? , or we can to ignore this check ?

Comment: @yael well, the packet MUST cross the switches, so you're indirectly testing those, too. Obviously, if a packet won't get through, it MIGHT be the server or it MIGHT be the switch! It's up to you to verify every configuration.